# C++ checking return codes

Tags: c++, printf, return-code

Is it worthwhile checking return codes for methods that should not fail ?

For example, I usually do:

```
char buf[MAXBUF];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(MAXBUF), "%s.%d", str, time);
```

Is it good practice to check the return code for snprintf even if I know
that MAXBUF is large enough for my purposes? It seems to make sense to do this
even though the code becomes more verbose.

Comment: If you're really passing `sizeof(MAXBUF)` as the length then I'd say yes, check the return value. It might alert you to something you missed ;-)

Comment: Don't use snprintf in C++ code?

Comment: Yes: because it help catches bugs like the above during testing. Of cours if you were really using C++ you would do it another way and let the libraries handle the resource management.

Comment: sizeof( buf ) avoids this bug, plus, if buf changes size you don't have another point in the code you have to change.

Comment: Sorry - sizeof(buf) was what I meant :-) Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

Short Answer: Yes

Long Answer: Yes because it catches silly mistakes like the below.

```
char buf[MAXBUF];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(MAXBUF), "%s.%d", str, time);

// sizeof(MAXBUF) is probably equal to sizeof(int)
```

The main problem with C code is that people don't actually check the return codes (because they thought the code could never fail). So the moral of the story is don't assume and check. It does not actually add much to the code. You should probably exit/abort if things that should not go wrong actually go wrong and then you will find them early in the testing cycle.

C++ solution:

```
std::stringstream  buf;
buf << str << "." << time;  // No chance of error as compiler does the work.
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  Is it possible that either `MAXBUF` or the format string or the input values are ever going to change in the future?  What realistic course of action could your code take if the call were to fail?  The answer depends entirely on your application.

One possibility is to simply `assert` that the return values are as expected, rather than failing silently.  This will cost you nothing in production builds, and will add little to the verbosity of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best, just incase, but if your sure the size of MAXBUF will never be exceeded then it will only be an added few clock cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You are weighing the onetime cost of a simple error check when the code is written, versus the repeated cost of deciding whether or not to check it depending on context, and if not, possible production bugs due to misunderstood assumptions or later maintenance by other people.

That's a no brainer in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the buffer ever is somehow too small, then the string will be truncated. You'd hope that your tests will catch this, since you will produce incorrect results.

Then again, checking the return value needn't add much verbosity. As Oli says, `assert` is cheap:

```
int result = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s.%d", str, time);
assert(result >= 0 && result <= (sizeof buf) - 1);
```

To be honest I wouldn't always check, but it depends why I think `str` can't be that long. If it's for a really fundamental reason (like it's a filename from a `dirent` structure, and `MAXBUF` is defined in terms of `MAX_FILENAME`), then I probably wouldn't bother. If it's because there's some check elsewhere, or it's the caller's responsibility to pass in a string only of a certain length, then it might be an idea to `assert`, just on the off-chance of catching someone else's bug some day. Obviously if `str` is any kind of unchecked external input then it's essential to test.